# How to add test steps to a coded ui test?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I have a coded ui test that is written in C#.

When the test case is opened in MTM, no test steps are observed.

I have associated the automated, and this seems to be ok.

I tried to add some methods in my test method, and commented these methods with a summary, but this didn't help.

I will need these steps and I would like them tied back into the code, how is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must create an action recording for your test case/steps. A test method is created per step. You can then edit those test methods manually.

If you've handcoded a codedUi test then you can only associated the codedUI test method to the overall test case. Manual test steps should indicate what the codedUI test is doing, but there it's no connection between the two.

See [Generating a Coded UI Test from an Existing Action Recording](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286652.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Test steps are added to test cases in MTM. Commonly they provide instructions for manual testing. Such a manual test can be recorded when executed through MTM and that is referred to as an "action recording". The recorded test can be executed again via MTM, that avoids the tester having to perform the text entry and mouse-clicking needed. However, the action recording will not perform any validations of the expected results; that must be done manually.

The next facility is that a Coded UI test can be created from an action recording. The new Coded UI test does not included any validations of the expected results but the facilities of Coded UI can be used to assertions that can make the test fully automated. Having created a Coded UI test it can be linked back to the test case and will then be seen in the "associated automation" part of the test case. The linkage is created via the "Team Explorer" window in Visual Studio.

The order of events stated in the question suggests that the Coded UI test was created without using an "action recording"; which is a perfectly valid approach. The Coded UI test was then linked to an MTM test case. MTM has no mechanisms to decode the Coded UI test to create the test steps.

It would be possible to create a test case in MTM and specify its test steps but have an associated Coded UI test that does something different.

Comment: Well this is the exact problem. It would be nice if it would automatically create steps from functions called within the test method body.